# SQL Server Round DateTime Up

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I need a function that rounds UP to the nearest x mins.  I found the one below, but it rounds up or down to the nearest x mins.  Based on another value, I would either need to round it UP to the nearest half hour or hour.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundTime] (@Time DATETIME, @RoundToMin INT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
RETURN ROUND(CAST(CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Time,121) AS DATETIME) AS FLOAT) * (1440/@RoundToMin),0)/(1440/@RoundToMin)
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change ROUND to CEILING and take away the ", 0" from the ROUND:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundTime] (@Time DATETIME, @RoundToMin INT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
RETURN CEILING(CAST(CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Time,121) AS DATETIME) AS FLOAT) * (1440/@RoundToMin))/(1440/@RoundToMin)
END
GO
```

Comment: Obviously, you might consider renaming your function since it no longer _"rounds"_.

Comment: I tried something similar to that previously and it didn't seem to always return the correct time.  For instance my next update time is calculate to be Nov 14 2012  3:33PM.  However, passing it to the function you provided it returns Nov 14 2012  3:59PM instead of 4:00pm.  Sometimes it calculates correctly.  Sometimes not.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I'll rename the function as appropriate.  I need to get it working first.

Comment: probably something to do with converting it to a FLOAT.  Decimals are more accurate.  I thought you were needing to round to minutes?

Answer (score 1):

This changes your function to round up to any number of minutes.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundUpTime] (@Time DATETIME, @RoundToMin INT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
return dateadd(mi, - datepart(mi, @time) + (datepart(mi, @time) + @roundToMin - 1) / @roundToMin * @roundToMin, @Time)
END
GO
```

Note I changed the name to RoundUpTime.  Caveat, it works on the MINUTE section only, and ignores seconds and milliseconds.

```
select dbo.RoundUpTime('20121212 12:30:00.003', 30)
--
2012-12-12 12:30
```

Comment: Sweet!  That seems to be working as expected.  Thanks a bunch!